# Bind different dom elements in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this HTML

```
  <div class="pageContent">
    <aside class="left-cont">
      <ul class="btn-menu" >
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ><a  class="ng-scope ng-binding" href="#" ng-click="show={{tab.id}}">   {{tab.name}}</a> </li> 
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <section class="main-content" ng-show="show === 1">
      <h1> {tab.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{tab.content}}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="main-content" ng-show="show === 2">
      <h1> {{tab.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{tab.content}}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="main-content" ng-show="show === 3">
      <h1> {{tab.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{tab.content}}</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

And I have three problems with it:

1)`ng-click="show={{tab.id}}"`shows me the right id number in the dom, for instance, id=1 does show `<a class="ng-scope ng-binding" href="#" ng-click="show=1">`but I do get an error in my console - `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=7&p3=show%3D%7B%7Btab.id%7D%7D&p4=%7Btab.id%7D%7D` Why is that? I have tried to to write tab.id instead of {{tab.id}}, but it doesn't even fetch the element.

2) I want the section tags to be appended whenever there's a click on the a, but I can not do so since the section tags aren't wrapped in the li tags (when I do put them in the li they do fire, but that's not what I want). How do I bind these two different elements?

3) I want each section to append the content of its specific tab for the section that has - `ng-show="show === 1"` I want tab.title and tab.content of the tab that has the id=1, and so on..

How is that all possible?

Help is very much appreciated here

Comment: Show hide by id, is still jQuery way of doing things. Not angular way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HarishR is right: this is not the AngularJS way to do things. The imperative way of doing things would be to have an ng-click set the isActive property to true on an instance of tab.
Then the directive would would watch the isActive property and change class accordingly.

Since you probably don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could consider using Angular strap ( http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tabs#tabs ) or check out this code https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js.